# Why getting errors in android studio when adding code to the main activity xml?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using android studio 2022 language is java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity: this, string[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO} , requestCode.1);
        }
    }
```

Getting errors in the line

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity: this, string[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO} , requestCode.1);
```

The activity is not exist it should be much smaller and in gray. requestCode also is not exist.

**Screenshot image of the errors:**

[image: screenshot image of the errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to take a course on `Java` in general before you start jumping into `Android` which far more complex. Every argument for `requestPermissions` is not valid `Java`

`activity: this` is not valid `Java`. Just use `this`.

`string[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}` is not valid `Java`. Change it to this
`new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}`

`requestCode.1` is not valid `Java` just use `1`

The end result should be this

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
```